# Compare variation between first and second row for group

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a "Empresas" table

```
dbo.empresas

    id | name | delegacion_id
    -------------------------
    1  |  A   |     3
    2  |  B   |     3
    3  |  C   |     3
    4  |  D   |     4
```

a "pagos" table

```
dbo.pagos


    id | id_empresa | monto  | periodo   
    ----------------------------------
    1  |   1        |  120   | 2012-11-01
    2  |   1        |  125   | 2012-12-01
    3  |   2        |  150   | 2012-11-01
    4  |   1        |  200   | 2013-01-01
    5  |   2        |  151   | 2012-12-01
```

I have a value X that is a percentage.

I need to show the "empresas" that, comparing the "montos" of their two last "pagos" (ordered by periodo), have changed at least +X% or -X%, from an especific id_delegacion

For example, if we run this query with these example values, considering

X = 10
id_delegacion = 3

the output expected will be:

```
name | periodo    | monto
---------------------------
A    | 2012-12-01 | 125 
A    | 2013-01-01 | 200
```

empresa A is from delegacion_id = 3, and the comparison between the last two pagos, ordered by periodo desc (200 => 125) is bigger than 10%.

B is not showed because the comparison is smaller than 10%.

C is not showed because has no row in "pagos" table

D is from another delegation.

How can I get this desired output? For the record, using MySQL 5.5.8.

**What I've done**

I got this

```
select P.id_empresa, max(periodo) as periodo from 
        pagos P
        where id_empresa in(
                                select e.id
                                from empresa E 
                                where E.id_delegacion = 3
                            ) 
        group by p.id_empresa, p.periodo
        having count(*) > 1
```

with these I got the "empresas" that have more than one "pago" row, and got id_delegation = 3.
Also get the first period (the maximum), but I don't know how to get the second for each empresa, and compare them.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is my query:

```
SELECT
  empresas.name,
  pagos.periodo,
  pagos.monto
FROM
  pagos INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      lst.id id1,
      prc.id id2
    FROM (
      SELECT
        p1.id_empresa,
        MAX(p1.periodo) last_p,
        MAX(p2.periodo) prec_p
      FROM
        pagos p1 INNER JOIN pagos p2
        ON p1.id_empresa = p2.id_empresa
           AND p2.periodo < p1.periodo
      GROUP BY
        id_empresa) latest
      INNER JOIN
      pagos lst ON lst.id_empresa = latest.id_empresa AND lst.periodo=latest.last_p
      INNER JOIN
      pagos prc ON prc.id_empresa = latest.id_empresa AND prc.periodo=latest.prec_p
    WHERE
      lst.monto > prc.monto * 1.1) ids
  ON pagos.id IN (ids.id1, ids.id2)
  INNER JOIN
  empresas
  ON pagos.id_empresa = empresas.id
WHERE
  delegacion_id=3
```

I think it can be simplified if you want to have values on the same row, e.g.

```
name | ultimo_periodo    | ultimo_monto | anterior_periodo | anterior_monto
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/baaef/1).

I still wondering if it can be simplified a little, but I am not sure if it is. Here's another solution:

```
SELECT
  empresas.name,
  pagos.periodo,
  pagos.monto
FROM
  pagos INNER JOIN empresas
  ON pagos.id_empresa = empresas.id
  INNER JOIN (
SELECT
  id_empresa,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row=1 THEN monto END) lst_monto,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row=2 THEN monto END) prc_monto,
  MAX(id) id1, MIN(id) id2
FROM (

  SELECT
    p1.*, COUNT(*) row
  FROM
    pagos p1 INNER JOIN pagos p2
    ON p1.id_empresa = p2.id_empresa
       AND p1.periodo <= p2.periodo
    INNER JOIN empresas
    ON p1.id_empresa = empresas.id
  WHERE
    empresas.delegacion_id = 3
  GROUP BY
    p1.id, p1.id_empresa, p1.monto, p1.periodo
  HAVING
    COUNT(*)<=2
  ORDER BY
    p1.id_empresa, p1.periodo desc
  ) s
GROUP BY
  id_empresa
HAVING
  lst_monto>prc_monto*1.1
) l ON pagos.id IN (l.id1, l.id2)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/baaef/21).

Comment: looks good, but I have to go. Tomorrow I'll check it !! thanks

Comment: wow that's really good. It will work, but now that you say, the alternative (show both in same row) it could be possible too. How will be in that case?